# Fatal error during add a field to a content type with a custom Field Type

Tags: entities

I'm working on Drupal 8 and I create a custom field type so

When I tried to add a field to a content type Drupal give me this error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Drupal\any_to_show\Plugin\Field\FieldType\AnyToShowItem in /var/www/public/sites/all/modules/something/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/AnyToShowItem.php on line 105

I'm confused because it suppose that the file is the definition and it says that I'm redeclaring the class, I search whole site but nothing.

I was grateful if somebody can help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you generate this code with Drupal Console or did you write it from scratch?

Comment: I do it from scratch using as reference the plugin telephone to make it right

Comment: Just a question, because I got similar error(s) before after generating code. Can you post your class so we can see the code?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, and the solution was making sure that the file name matches the class name defined within, so in your case, the class name MUST be `AnyToShowItem`.

This is because the PSR-4 auto-loader would be trying to load `.../sites/all/modules/something/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/AnyToShowItem.php` if the class `AnyToShowItem` doesn't exist. But if the class defined within doesn't match the filename, then `AnyToShowItem` will still be undefined but the class that IS contained in the file will be. So the next time the `AnyToShowItem` class is attempted to be constructed, the file is loaded again in a futile attempt to define the class, but the class within will already have been defined, and thus the redefinition error will be thrown